# JFace wizard passing variables

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, wizard

I'm trying to produce a wizard using the `Wizard` class (org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard)

Basically where I extend the `Wizard` in the constructor I `addPage` the two pages I want.

On my first page I take some credentials.

On the second page I want to run a query against the database using the credentials from the first page to populate a table with names.

How do I go about passing these values from the first to the second page?

To all intents and purposes my code at present is the same as http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Asurveyusingawizard.htm except I obtain some strings from some text boxes on the first page and have a table on the second page.

I have read about containers and see there is a setData() method, is this something I can utilize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to create my data object in the Wizard and pass it into the constructor of each of my WizardPages.  For example:

```
public void addPages() {
  data = new MyData()
  addPage(new FirstPage(data));
  addPage(new SecondPage(data));
  ...
}
```

One advantage to this approach is you have access to your data object during your wizard's performFinish.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do this:

```
PageOne pageOne = (PageOne) getWizard().getPreviousPage(this);
```

Supposing you are on PageTwo, and in PageOne you have defined your getters for the values you wish to use on PageTwo.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a data class with static variables.  For example, if you have a NewVehicleWizard, you may have to instantiate Car, Truck, or SUV (all subclasses of Vehicle).  But that will not be known when the wizard is instantiated; that decision will be made in a VehicleTypePage, which could make the following method call when the option Truck is selected:

```
MyWizardData.setVehicle(new Truck());
```

MyWizardData will have a private static vehicle variable with static getter and setter.  If the vehicle object is needed by a subsequent page or by the NewVehicleWizard itself, you can simply use the static getter:

```
Truck truck = (Truck)MyWizardData.getVehicle();
// ...work with truck here
```