# Passing data between JFace wizard pages

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a "New Project type" plugin in our company. The problem I am facing is, I want to pass data selected on one of the wizard page to next wizard page. Consider there are two wizards `wizard1` and `wizard2`. In `wizard1` there are few checkboxes, and I need to pass these values to `wizard2`. How can I achieve this?

I searched a lot and found these two questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080773/how-to-pass-data-between-jface-wizard-pages) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157113/jface-wizard-passing-variables) But in those two links, they are creating data initially and then passing it to all of other wizards in constructor. But my situation is, user selects few checkboxes in `wizard1` and I need those values in `wizard2`. Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this? Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Note:** I am very beginner in Eclipse Plugin Development, and not asking complete code, but an idea (like is there any built in method to pass values between pages etc etc)

I am creating Wizards like this:

```
public void addPages() {
   addPage(new Wizard1("Wizard1")); //User selects checkbox here
   addPage(new Wizard2("Wizard2")); //I need to access those values in this wizard
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture wizard page data in a shared Object.

```
example code:

new WizardPage1(sharedObject)

new WizardPage2(sharedObject)

WizardPage1:

checkBtn.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

public void handleEvent(Event e){

   sharedObject.setCheck(true);

}

});
```